# Javascript: Detect when move a browser window

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any way to know for events when move a window with "window.open"?.

It may be with javascript or using jQuery

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you mean the physical browser window itself, no.  Javascript runs sandboxed within the context of the window; you can't handle events outside of it.

Comment: ok, the only way I found so far is going to consult with a setTimeout the position of the window to see if he moved